# Why does exec raise a syntax error when given python string?

Tags: python, exec

I have this python code

```
while 1:
    exec(input())
```

when I enter `import os \nos.system("echo 1")` I get this error

```
  File "<string>", line 1
    import os \nos.system("echo 1")
                                  ^
SyntaxError: unexpected character after line continuation character
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you're using `\n` within the `exec`, which as @The Thonnu mentioned causes problems when parsing.

Try entering `import os; os.system("echo 1")` instead.

Semicolons can be used in Python to separate different lines as an alternative to semicolons.

If you must use `\n` in your input, you can also use:

```py
while 1:
    exec(input().replace('\\n', '\n'))
```

Answer (score 1):

`exec` reads the `\n` as a backslash and then n (`'\\n'`) not `'\n'`.

A backslash is a line continuation character which is used at the end of a line, e.g.:

```py
message = "This is really a long sentence " \
          "and it needs to be split across mutliple " \
          "lines to enhance readibility of the code"
```

If it recieves a character after a backslash, it raises an error.

You can use a semicolon to indicate a new expression:

```py
import os; os.system("echo 1")
```

Or, replace the `'\n'`s in your code:

```py
exec(input().replace('\\n', '\n'))
```

Answer (score 1):

When you enter the line:

```
import os \nos.system("echo 1")
```

In Python, this string actually looks like this:

```
import os \\nos.system("echo 1")
```

Because it's trying to treat your input as literally having a `\`, which requires a `\\`. It doesn't treat your `\n` as a newline.

You could remove the escape yourself:

```
cmd = input()
exec(cmd.replace("\\n", "\n"))
```